# Error when deploying the gatsby app with gatsby-source-buttercms on Zeit

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, content-management-system, gatsby

My code: https://github.com/who-know-cg/main-gatsby

Every time I build my Gatsby app (on Zeit) I get this error message:

```
ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-transformer-json" threw an error while running the onCreateNode lifecycle:

Could not find function loadNodeContent for plugin gatsby-source-buttercms

Error: Could not find function loadNodeContent for plugin gatsby-source-butter  cms
```

And I never meet this error when in developing using `gatsby develop`.

Here is a similar question on github https://github.com/ldd/gatsby-source-github-api/issues/10 .
But I don't know what the answer means, and I don't know if it's the same issue either.

Please help me find what part is going wrong, thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't gotten an answer yet there is a temporary workaround this issue. The github you've linked itself is very helpful.

Take the source code and use it as a local plugin. 
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-a-local-plugin/

Change the mediaType in the source code from `application/json` to `text/plain`. This should be a working temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

npm install Pearce-Ropion/gatsby-source-apiserver#6112115 -D
yarn add Pearce-Ropion/gatsby-source-apiserver#6112115 -D